# When using structopt, how to test if the user provided an option or if it comes from the default value?

Tags: rust, structopt

I'm using the `structopt` crate and I have the following struct:

```
#[derive(Clone, StructOpt, Debug)]
#[structopt(name = "test")]
pub struct CommandlineOptions {
    #[structopt(
    long = "length",
    help = "The length of the the string to generate",
    default_value = "50",
    index = 1
    )]
    pub length: usize,
}


let options = CommandlineOptions::from_args();
```

If `options.length` is `50`, how can I know it comes from the default value 50, or the user provided a value of 50?

Comment: If you want to know that (FWR) you may should use an `Option` and check if that's `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do this with `structopt`. The idiomatic way to solve this problem is to instead use an `Option<usize>` instead of `usize` (as documented [here](https://docs.rs/structopt/0.3.23/structopt/index.html#type-magic)):

```rust
use structopt::StructOpt;

#[derive(Clone, StructOpt, Debug)]
#[structopt(name = "test")]
pub struct CommandlineOptions {
    #[structopt(
    long = "length",
    help = "The length of the the string to generate",
    index = 1
    )]
    pub length: Option<usize>,
}

fn main() {
    let options = CommandlineOptions::from_args();
    println!("Length parameter was supplied: {}, length (with respect to default): {}", options.length.is_some(), options.length.unwrap_or(50));
}
```

If this does not work in your case somehow, you could also directly work with the `clap::ArgMatches` struct (`structopt` is little more than macro magic around `clap`) to check the number of occurrences of `length` with [`ArgMatches::occurrences_of`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.3/clap/struct.ArgMatches.html#method.occurrences_of). However, this wouldn't be very idiomatic.

```rust
use structopt::StructOpt;

#[derive(Clone, StructOpt, Debug)]
#[structopt(name = "test")]
pub struct CommandlineOptions {
    #[structopt(
    long = "length",
    help = "The length of the the string to generate",
    default_value = "50",
    index = 1
    )]
    pub length: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let matches = CommandlineOptions::clap().get_matches();
    let options = CommandlineOptions::from_clap(&matches);
    
    let length_was_supplied = match matches.occurrences_of("length") {
        0 => false,
        1 => true,
        other => panic!("Number of occurrences is neither 0 nor 1, but {}. This should never happen.", other)
    };
    
    println!("Length parameter was supplied: {}, length (with respect to default): {}", length_was_supplied, options.length);
}
```